# where does the Editable.append() implemented?

Tags: java, android

Here is the code :

```
Editable text = (Editable)mResults.getText();     //mResults is a TextView.
```

I want to know, when i call `text.append("***")`,which implements is called? I can't find where the Editable interface is implemented.

Answer (score 0):

Start looking in TextView class and continue to his superclasses.
The first method you will encounter will be the one that's actually gets invoked.

Comment: Wait. I got it wrong... It is somewhat trickier. You can either debug and see which class mResults.getText() return, or look in TextView sources...

Comment: Or just print your 'text' object to the output and you'll see the implementation class.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Editable.html) link only builtin public implementation is [SpannableStringBuilder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableStringBuilder.html)
see Known indirect subclasses node. If you want to resolve it during runtime you'll have to use reflection and iterate over class hierarchy of particular instance